# Is there a way for me to invite other StackExchange users to follow a proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51, invitation

I've created a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22684/juggling?referrer=E1cigASoD0XlNnj4FbhjeA2), and I know of some other StackExchange/Area51 [users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/1268/crazyjugglerdrummer) who are likely to be interested in the proposal.

Is there a way I can send an invite to another user on the site? I would expect that you could, but the "share this" link only gives me a link to send to people by some other means (and since I can't private message people, I don't want to just junk up some unrelated thread by posting it there), and buttons to share it on various social networking sites.

Comment: I really don't like this idea.  The last thing I want to have to do is wade through spam on my StackExchange Inbox.

Comment: By the way, instead of posting a comment or downvoting, you could answer "no, such a feature doesn't exist," possibly with an explanation of why you think it's a bad idea. I am asking if a feature exists, not requesting it.

Comment: You could see if perhaps the user is using one of the SE chats.  Or if they have any info in their profile such as a twitter id or blog or email.  Still though, nobody wants to get spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really -- this is a stealth request for private messaging, which we don't support.

Comment: OK, fair enough. This wasn't intended as a request, just a question of whether such a feature exists or not. I was expecting that there might be something more limited than private messaging that would allow you to suggest that someone might be interested in a particular SE proposal. But if not, that's fine.